# CSURF returns EBADCSRFTOKEN while the token is written wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, ejs, csrf

I'm using csurf to protect against csrf attacks.

Now for some reason the requests stopped working because of the following error:

```
 message: 'invalid csrf token', code: 'EBADCSRFTOKEN'
```

Now I checked what's the csrf token and here's something strange I get this:

```
{ csrfToken:
   '\n                miXCD9Di-HtygtQPxEVhUETpYQDHrKM5auE8\n            ' }
```

Which should normally be:

```
{ csrfToken:'miXCD9Di-HtygtQPxEVhUETpYQDHrKM5auE8'}
```

Now I checked everywhere but can't seem to find what's causing this.

Here's some of the source code:
EDIT.EJS:

```
 <p id="csurf" style="display: none;">
            <%=csurf%>
        </p>
```

APPROVE.JS:

```
const csurf = document.getElementById("csurf").innerText.toString();

//more functionality
const data = {
    name: bizName.value,
    email: bizEmail.value,
    location: getlocation(),
    owner: {
      firstName: ownerFname.value,
      lastName: ownerLname.value,
    },
    phone: phone.value,
    website: bizUrl.value,
    category: selectedCat,
    logo: logoImage,
    _csrf: csurf, //here i send it to the server
  };
```

BUSINESS.JS //Serverside code

```
res.render("business/admin/edit", {
  title: `Edit ${doc.name}`,
  csurf: req.csrfToken(),
  biz: { ...doc, id: paramId },
});
```

APP.JS //here is the error handler and the setup

```
const session = require("express-session");
const csurf = require("csurf");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");


const csrfMiddleware = csurf({
  cookie: true,
});
app.use(csrfMiddleware);

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err);

  if (err.code !== "EBADCSRFTOKEN") return next(err);
  // error handler
  console.log(req.cookies._csrf);
  var csrfToken = req.body._csrf.toString();
  console.log({csrfToken});
  // handle CSRF token errors here
  res.status(403);
  logger.warn(`Bad CSRF token: ${req.connection.remoteAddress}`);
  res.json({ message: "form tampered with", success: false });
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the newline and spaces that are inside the `<p>` in your template. You can just use `.trim()` to remove them:

```
const csurf = document.getElementById("csurf").innerText.trim();
```

You can alternatively just remove the newline and spaces:

```
<p id="csurf" style="display: none;"><%=csurf%></p>
```